# Having trouble upgrading to RSpec 3

Tags: rspec, rubygems, rspec-rails

I am trying to upgrade my test suite to RSpec 3.  After reading the documentation of how to do it I followed all the steps...  I have upgraded to 2.99.2 and ran the transpec gem(awesome!) I am left with one deprecation... this:

```
`require 'rspec-expectations'` is deprecated. Use `require'rspec/expectations'` instead. Called from     /Users/kierancormack/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.8.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'.
```

I don't understand what i am supposed to do.  I have changed my Gemfile to look like this but it just throws an error.  I have required it in my spec_helper.rb but i just can't seem to make it disappear!

Anyone have any suggestions of how to deal with this deprecation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

RSpec 2.x provided an [`rspec/expectations`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/v2.14.5/lib/rspec-expectations.rb) file which simply delegates to `require 'rspec/expectations'`.  However, the general convention in the ruby community is for dashes in gem names to correspond to a `/` in the top-level file name -- so most ruby programmers would know that gem `x-y` should be required using `x/y`.  As part of our 3.0 spring cleaning we removed the `rspec-expectations` file as it's an unneeded layer of indirection.  So, you need to require `rspec/expectations` instead of `rspec-expectations`.

In your case, the stack trace makes it look like the `require` is happening inside Bundler.  When you use `Bundler.require` it tries to require a file matching the gem name for each gem in the `Gemfile`. There are [good reasons to avoid `Bundler.require`](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/12/5-reasons-to-avoid-bundler-require) but if you're going to use it, the fix here is to add `:require => "rspec/expectations"` to the `gem 'rspec-expectations'` line in your `Gemfile`.

Actually, if you're using `rspec-core` (on its own, or via `rspec-rails`), you don't need to require `rspec/expectations` at all; `rspec-core` will load it at the appropriate time for you, so you can use `:require => false` to prevent bundler from trying to require it.

In fact, we can take this a step forward: `rspec-core` and `rspec-rails` both depend upon `rspec-expectations` so you generally don't need to put `rspec-expectations` in your `Gemfile` *at all* unless you are doing something special (e.g. trying to use a fork or HEAD from github) or you are using it on its own w/o `rspec-core` or `rspec-rails`. So unless you have a specific reason to list `rspec-expectations` in your `Gemfile`, I recommend you remove it.